# Decrease /home and increase /root without losing data

Tags: centos, lvm

How can I increase my /root partition by 100G by reducing /home quickly and without losing data?

```
[root@server-dolphin ~]# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk
└─sda1            8:1    0   2.7T  0 part /mnt
nvme0n1         259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0 930.5G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0  31.4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 799.1G  0 lvm  /home
```

Comment: This is a good guide to managing the size of LVM partitions. https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/  Your data should be safe but there is always some risk with this kind of thing. However if your data is valuable you should have backups. If you don’t now is a good time to make a backup before changing the partitions

Comment: +1 one for the backup recommendation. I don't think the link is particularly good, though.

Comment: ... And this is why it's always worth keeping your filesystems smaller rather than larger. There's no need to allocate the entirety of your VG at the beginning. 20GB for / and similar for /home might well have been sufficient. If you need 200GB for / you ought to consider whether you need a separate partition. Upgrades typically flatten /

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to use e.g. a [SystemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue.org/Download/), and use gparted to do the resizing while the filesystems aren't mounted.

Regarding the shrinking: you may be out of luck if you went with the *DeadRat* default filesystem `xfs`, it only allows for growing.